# UDP Checksum calculation error, Java

Tags: java, networking, udp, ipv4

I've been trying to correctly calculate the UDP checksum value for a networks assignment. I create a IPv4 style packet, formatted to UDP which I then send to the assignment server. It then responds with a magic number which correlates to the outcome. The data size that I send starts at 2 bytes, and doubles for every packet up to 1024, and each byte has a random value. For each packet I send, the server responds with 0xCAFEBABE if it is correct, and 0xDEADC0DE if the UDP checksum is incorrect. Occasionally, the first few packets will come back correct before returning 0xDEADC0DE.

Here is my code for calculating a new packet, I apologize in advance for the spaghetti code, I usually work through a problem and try to understand the mechanisms before I optimize:

```
//Heres the mess.
    public static byte[] recalculatePacket(int size,Random random, boolean overwrite, byte[] custom, byte protocol, boolean udp, int udpport) {
        byte versionAndIHL = 69;
        byte tos = 0;
        short length;
        if(udp){
            length = (short)(28 + size);
        }else{
            length = (short)(20 + size);
        }
        short ident = 0;
        short flagsAndFrag = 1;
        flagsAndFrag <<= 14;
        byte ttl = 50;
        int checksum = 0;
        int sourceAddr = 1824010952;
        int destAddr = 874862746;
        short sourcePort = 0;
        int destPort = udpport;
        short udplength = (short)(8 + size);
        long udpchecksum = 0;
        int[] checksumCount = new int[22];
        int[] udpchecksumCount = new int[(10 + (size/2))];
        byte[] temp;
        if(udp){
            temp = new byte[(28+size)];
        }else{
            temp = new byte[(20+size)];
        }
        //IPv4 Initializing section.
        temp[0] = versionAndIHL;
        temp[1] = tos;
        temp[2] = (byte) (length >> 8);
        temp[3] = (byte) (length);
        temp[4] = (byte) (ident >> 8);
        temp[5] = (byte) (ident);
        temp[6] = (byte) (flagsAndFrag >> 8);
        temp[7] = (byte) (flagsAndFrag);
        temp[8] = ttl;
        temp[9] = protocol;
        temp[10] = 0;
        temp[11] = 0;
        temp[12] = (byte) (sourceAddr >> 24);
        temp[13] = (byte) (sourceAddr >> 16);
        temp[14] = (byte) (sourceAddr >> 8);
        temp[15] = (byte) (sourceAddr);
        temp[16] = (byte) (destAddr >> 24);
        temp[17] = (byte) (destAddr >> 16);
        temp[18] = (byte) (destAddr >> 8);
        temp[19] = (byte) (destAddr);

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j += 2) {
            checksumCount[(j / 2)] += (short) (temp[j] << 8);
            checksumCount[(j / 2)] += (short) (temp[(j + 1)] & 0xFF);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            checksum += checksumCount[i];
        }

        if(overwrite && !udp){
            for(int n = 20; n < (20+size); n++){
                temp[n] = custom[(n-20)];
            }
        }

        checksum++;
        checksum = ~checksum;
        temp[10] = (byte) (checksum >> 8);
        temp[11] = (byte) (checksum & 0xFF);        

        //UDP initializing section.
        if(udp){
        temp[20] = (byte) (sourcePort >> 8);
        temp[21] = (byte) (sourcePort);
        temp[22] = (byte) (destPort >> 8);
        temp[23] = (byte) (destPort);
        temp[24] = (byte) (udplength >> 8);
        temp[25] = (byte) (udplength);

        udpchecksumCount[0] += (short)(sourceAddr >> 16);
        udpchecksumCount[1] += (short)(sourceAddr);
        udpchecksumCount[2] += (short)(destAddr >> 16);
        udpchecksumCount[3] += (short)(destAddr);
        udpchecksumCount[4] += (short)protocol;
        udpchecksumCount[5] += (short)udplength;
        udpchecksumCount[6] += (short)sourcePort;
        udpchecksumCount[7] += (short)destPort;
        udpchecksumCount[8] += (short)udplength;
        udpchecksumCount[9] += (short) 0;

        byte[] randomData = new byte[size];
        random.nextBytes(randomData);

        //Assigning random values
        for(int p = 0; p < size; p++){
            temp[(p+28)] = randomData[p];
        }

        //Appending values into shorts and storing.
        for (int m = 0; m < (size/2); m++){
            udpchecksumCount[(m+10)] += (short)(temp[((2*m)+28)] << 8);
            udpchecksumCount[(m+10)] += (short)(temp[((2*m)+29)] & 0xFF);
        }

        //Adding all values to checksum
        System.out.println(destPort);
        for(int n = 0; n < (10 + (size/2)); n++){
            udpchecksum +=  udpchecksumCount[n];
            if(((udpchecksum & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16) >= 1){
                long hold = ((udpchecksum & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
                udpchecksum &= 0xFFFF;
                udpchecksum += hold;
                System.out.println("procced");
            }
            //if(n > 9)
                System.out.println(n + "\t" + udpchecksumCount[n] + "\t\t" + (udpchecksum));
        }
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + (udpchecksum));
        udpchecksum++;
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + (udpchecksum));
            if(((udpchecksum & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16) >= 1){
                long hold = ((udpchecksum & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
                udpchecksum &= 0xFFFF;
                udpchecksum += hold;
                System.out.println("procced");
            }
        udpchecksum = ~udpchecksum;
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + (udpchecksum));

        temp[26] = (byte) (udpchecksum >> 8);
        temp[27] = (byte) (udpchecksum & 0xFF);
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `temp[20] = (byte) (sourcePort);` twice. Compare the next two lines.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that the sourcePort can be any value so long as I keep it consistent across all the packets, so I just made it 0,  but I've changed it now to follow the same trend as the rest of the array's data entry.

Comment: Makes no difference. You are still not sending the high byte.

Comment: I've changed that section to be:
        temp[20] = (byte) (sourcePort >> 8);
        temp[21] = (byte) (sourcePort);
This sends both the high and low bytes, right?

Comment: Of course, and are you still getting the problem? If so you should update your post with the current code.

Comment: The problem still persists, but now the first two packets are accepted more consistently before I receive the dead response.